# Executing A complex Shell command read as String from a File in Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, plumbum

I have a configuration file where user can specify a set of shell commands.
Commands are basically a chain of pipe-separated shell commands.

```
CMD1 = grep "SomeOtherString" | grep "XX" | cut -d":" -f9 | cut -d"," -f1

CMD2 = grep "SomeOtherString" | tail -1| cut -d":" -f9 | cut -d"," -f1 | cut -d"[" -f2 | cut -d"]" -f1
```

I am able to read the commands in my Python scripts. My question is how will I be able to run these read command strings in Python and get the output.

Any solution with `subprocess`, `plumbum`, `sh` will be acceptable.

Comment: if you know about subprocess, why not try it? https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html , https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1393/subprocess-library#t=201704070552204503464

Comment: As an aside, your pipelines look like they want to be small Awk scripts instead.  `CMD1 = awk -F: '/SomeOtherString/ && /XX/ { s=$9; sub(/,.*/, "", s); print s }'` and `CMD2 = awk -F: '/SomeOtherString { s=$9; sub(/][^],]*,.*/, "", s); sub(/^[^[]*\[/, "", s); } END { print s }'`

Comment: @tripleee yes , it can have awk commands too : grep "Something" ${LOGFILE}|tail -1|awk -F"=" '{ print $3 }'

Comment: My point is that your scripts probably should probably be written entirely, or at least predominantly in Awk.  Once you have more than two or three `grep` and `cut` and `tail` commands in a pipeline, you should start thinking.  And of course, your latest example is much better written `awk -F= '/Something/ { s=$3 } END { print s }' "$LOGFILE"`

Comment: Thanks .. we ll m more inclined to know what issues can occur if i pass a chain of commands as string to python subprocesss

Answer (score 2):

Use [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)()

```
output = subprocess.check_output(output)
```

Something to be aware of is that unlike the other subprocess commands, a subprocess.CalledProcessError will be raised if a non-zero error code is returned.

---

You shouldn't need to do this, but in case it comes in handy to somebody out there, I did run into an experience once where for some reason the above solution did not work, and so, instead, I did the following.

```
    stdout_fh = io.StringIO()
    stderr_fh = io.StringIO()
    with redirect_stderr(stderr_fh):
        with redirect_stdout(stdout_fh):
            subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
    stderr = stderr_fh.getvalue()
    stdout = stderr_fh.getvalue()
```